# Parallel Programming in AMD based laptop

Tags: windows-10, multi-core, parallel-processing, amd-graphics-card, amd-cpu

I've a Lenovo G50 series laptop with AMD A8-6410 @2Ghz, 8 GB RAM with a R5 230M and Radeon HD 8550M cards inside.

In Windows 10 is it possible to run a CLI based program ( ffmpeg for video compression to be specific ) using all the cores of the CPU and GPU or say 2 instances of it in separate processors to speed up / improve performance?

If so how?

Comment: This is vague specification of the problem. For such a question an answer would be: run multiple cmd windows and there you can run multiple processes from CLI. Whenever you start a new process the additional resources are asigned automatically.

Comment: I know I can run multiple instances of cmd, I wanna know of I can use my AMD GPUs processing power for any program

Comment: The program must be created to make the use of it, otherwise it is not possible, as far as I know.

Comment: NVidia enables it, but it is settings for the developers, not end users https://developer.nvidia.com/about-cuda

Comment: I did mention I have AMD all-in-all

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to use GPU as an additional computing resource, but this option is not available to the end user, it is an option for a developer. So as an end user you cannot tell a program of your choice to use your GPU, it is a developer's job to enable it.

For AMD it is called OpenCL, see following links:

http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/opencl-zone/

https://streamcomputing.eu/blog/2015-03-16/how-to-install-opencl-on-windows/

As a user you can run OpenCL program but you cannot force any normal non-OpenCL app to behave as OpenCL app, it is not possible.

Here is a list of OpenCL enabled AMD products:

http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/opencl-zone/amd-accelerated-parallel-processing-app-sdk/system-requirements-driver-compatibility/